# adding piece of HTML code using JS based on URL accessed

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to achieve is if a particular page is loaded in the browser for e.g www.domain.com/page then the following piece of code should be added in the page dynamically using JS (similar to how we load the Google Analytics code)

```
<div id="something">
  <img src="http://domain.com/images/someImage.jpg">
</div>
```

I am trying to figure the script which will load the above mentioned HTML code (anywhere of the page - www.domain.com/page)

Edit 1:

what I am trying to achieve is when the user goes to www.domain.com/page.html I am calling another page lets say page1.html which should contain the script which insert the HTML code I posted above. So I simply want to insert the function which should be enclosed in the  tag inside page1.html. Unfortunately I can not edit www.domain.com/page.html

Comment: and what have you tried? where is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to PLACE that code anywhere in your page using javascript, you first need to identify that PLACE in DOM Using an "id" attribute. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="target1"></div>
<div id="target2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var html = '<div id="something"><img src="http://domain.com/images/someImage.jpg"></div>';
document.getElementById('target1').innerHTML = html;
document.getElementById('target2').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not care about a specific div. I have updated my question for more clarification. I simply want to insert the exact piece of code anywhere inside the body tag in page.html via page1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $("#something").append("<img src='"+ url +"' />");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you save this code in a html-file named something.html

```
$(".documentholder").load("something.html");
```

in this case the class "documentholder" is the container you put the code in

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".documentholder").load("code.html");
```

If you a specific id of something

```
$(".documentholder").load("code.html #someid");
```

If you a specific tag and id of something

```
$(".documentholder").load("code.html #someid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are,

just change this part **if (getFileName() == "js")**  with **if (getFileName() == "page")**

I added js because that is what is returning in the code snippet :)

```js
function getFileName() {  
  var url = document.location.href; 
  url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("#") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("#")); 
  url = url.substring(0, (url.indexOf("?") == -1) ? url.length : url.indexOf("?"));  
  url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length);
  
  return url;
}


var div = '<div id="something"><img src="http://domain.com/images/someImage.jpg"></div>';


if (getFileName() == "js") {
  $('body').append(div);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```